# How to get particular file from lapply output in R?

Tags: r, file, lapply

I am reading files this way which seems to be quite fast:

```
dirPath = paste0("D:/test")
setwd(dirPath)
SF <- list.files(recursive=T, pattern=paste(".csv"), full.names=TRUE)
myfiles = lapply(SF, fread)
```

SF returns the following data:

```
./SubFolderA/1.csv
./SubFolderA/2.csv
./SubFolderA/3.csv

./SubFolderB/1.csv
./SubFolderB/2.csv
./SubFolderB/3.csv
```

So, I have two subfolders with 3 CSV files inside each subfolder. The number of CSV files is always the same in subfolders.

Question: Given `myfiles`, how can I select CSV files that are located inside SubFolderB? I need to individually access to 1.csv, 2.csv and 3.csv of this subfolder.

Comment: @MrFlickr: Thanks! Also, another issue I've just noticed: Let's say I have some 40 files inside Subfolder A with the names 1.csv,2.csv,...40.csv. These CSV files are stored in myfiles in the following sequence: 1,10,11,12,2,21,22,3,31,32, etc. Is there any way to sequence then as 1,2,3,etc.? If not, how can I generate indexes like 1,10,11,12,2,21.. in order to process files in the correct order. The thing is that I must know that, e.g. 2nd element is 2.csv (or 10.csv)

Comment: @MrFlick: Many thanks! Why don't you post the answer? Just only comment

Comment: I use comments when i'm guessing what the problem might be or don't have time to type up a proper answer but can offer the OP a point in the right direction. If i find that my comments fully satisfy the original question, i'll move them to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `list.files()` just returns a character vector, you can use function like `grep` to search for particular values in the list. If you want to find files in "SubFolderB" (and you don't want to just re-run `list.files()` in that directory), you can do

```
foldB <- grep("/SubFolderB/", SF, value=T)
foldB
# [1] "./SubFolderB/1.csv" "./SubFolderB/2.csv" "./SubFolderB/3.csv"
```

Then it's not really a good idea to assume that the files will be returned in any particular order. So if you want to know the "ID" for each file, it's better to parse that information out from the filename itself. For example

```
gsub("\\.[^.]*$","",basename(foldB))
# [1] "1" "2" "3"
```

we use `basename()` to remove the folder information, and we use `gsub()` to remove the file extension.